# Extracting certain text from rows in a collection in power apps

Tags: svg, uri, powerapps, power-automate

Im working on a flow which exports a uri link of an svg file, stored in a collection and returns it as a svg. For refrence here is that flow:

here im taking the uri , using the inbuilt function and then replacing the text
'data:image/svg xml' with a blank because it causes an error while making the SVG.
This was while i was doing it for one argument.

[image]

This is what the collection looks like.

[image]

now i have a collection of uri links that i want to do the same with. While exporting all of them together would be a good way , even seperate svg file is fine as long as i can send them together in one email.

Tried doing this but here its merging both of the files together, is there a way to take input one by one

[image]

i want different svg files for each svg URI

Edit:
realised that the code that was saving the values in the collection was joining the svg URI links of all the images.

```
ClearCollect(
    SVGCollection,
    {   

 

        SVG: 
            ForAll(
                Distinct(
                    Coords,
                    PageNo 
                ),
                "data:image/svg+xml,"&EncodeUrl("<svg height='100%' width='100%' viewBox='2 400 2000 180 xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>"&                          Concat(ForAll(Filter(Coords,PageNo=1),"<text x='"&Left&"' y='"&Top&"' font-family='Arial' font-size='16'             fill='black'>"&Text&"</text>"),Value)&"</svg>")
             )
        }
    );
```

this is the code, could someone guide me so as to how i can dynamically get the current PageNo from the ForAll loop instead of having to manually enter the value.

Comment: Sorry but you need to post the text as TEXT, not an image. It’s unreadable at present.

Comment: @Skin its just a URI Link in a collection nothing more

Comment: Still can’t help without it.

Comment: lol your SVG saga continues @AnrunyaPatole :)

Comment: @mmikesy90 ahahahah hello there!

Comment: @Skin thank you so much for asking that, i was going through the text and realised that the code that was saving the values in the collection was joining the svg URI links of all the images.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use `ForAll()` in PowerApps on your collection of raw SVGs and call the flow separately for each one, rather combining all files into a single text and then separate it again in Power Automate.

Thus your Power Automate logic will remain simple, reusable, easier to debug, etc.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense but the problem is that i need to send the file in a mail and sending an email for every svg will end up being a problem

Comment: but thank you so much for the suggestions man you're a legend

Comment: realised that i can just create a folder and append files to them whose link i can share

Comment: Yeah, always try to bend business expectations to your favour if your a developer :D

Comment: just an intern but im learning XD